# mfc - Why Different Drawing Arc and Ellipse?

Tags: mfc, automatic-ref-counting, gdi, ellipse

I want draw arc have big Radius using gdi.

Drawing is Success.

but arc is wrong.

so, I draw ellipse.

ellipse is Correct.

why that Two Drawing is Different??

Thanks For your Reading.

```
CClientDC dc(this);
CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 1, 0xff0000);
dc.SetArcDirection(AD_COUNTERCLOCKWISE);
CPoint ptTopLeft(-1290, 203);
CPoint ptBottomRight(4009, 5502);
CPoint ptStart(550, 329);
CPoint ptEnd(356, 400);

dc.Arc(ptTopLeft.x, ptTopLeft.y, ptBottomRight.x, ptBottomRight.y, ptStart.x, ptStart.y, ptEnd.x, ptEnd.y);
dc.SelectStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
dc.Ellipse(ptTopLeft.x, ptTopLeft.y, ptBottomRight.x, ptBottomRight.y);
```

[image]

Comment: Almost certainly rounding differences between the two functions. The start/end points of the arc are probably being projected to point(s) that are a half-pixel different from the ellipse. There's really nothing you can do about this.

Comment: Thank you For Answer. I'll find another Way.

Comment: Ok - one way might be to use `Arc` to also draw the complete ellipse (just thinking out loud).